# Link current WSS installation to a new Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory, wss, wss-3.0

I am faced with a problem of having to link a current setup of WSS 3.0 (SharePoint) to a newly built Active Directory and do not want to have to re-link all my users back into People and Groups on the SharePoint installation.

I have the following setup:
**Server 1** - SBS2003 Server running Active Directory and Exchange
**Server 2** - SQL Server running SQL server 2005
**Server 3** - WSS 3 / SharePoint Web Front End Server

I need to replace **Server 1** and it will be replaced with an SBS2008 (64-bit) server to run Active Directory and Exchange (This will be, for example, Server 4).

My setup of SharePoint (which is across server 2 and server 3) will need to use the new Active Directory on the new Server 4.

Is there a way I can link my current WSS 3.0 setup to the new (rebuilt) Active Directory without having to remove and re-add all my users into People and Groups in SharePoint and therefore saving me from having to update all my people fields within my site with new ones so my dynamic list filters (using the '[Me]' function) will work properly?

I hope this makes sense and any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is really a serverfault.com question.  You should post the question there.  Anyway, here is what I know.  The general idea is that you should be able to setup another domain controller for the same domain.  Then, let the old domain controller replicating the data to the new domain controller.  Move the FSMO roles from old domain controller to new domain controller.  Then, enable the new domain controller as Gobal Catalog.  Take out your old domain controller and then install the Exchange on your new server.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. My issue is more from the SharePoint / WSS side.  I am trying to find out how to re-link SharePoint to the new Active Directory that will be built in a seemless manner so i dont have to rebuild my People and Groups and permissions in WSS... Any ideas?

Comment: I am not SharePoint expert.  However, I do know something in Active Directory.  I don't expect you need to do any change on SharePoint/WSS side after you migrate to user another domain controller.  Once you setup a new domain controller in the same domain, the user and groups are replicated to new domain controller automatically.  The data is going to be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141%28office.12%29.aspx

```
stsadm -o migrateuser

   -oldlogin <domain\name>

   -newlogin <domain\name>

   [-ignoresidhistory]
```

Comment: This for this djeeg.  It looks like this will solve my problem.  It doesnt matter where the Active Directory is because this command sorts all my users out in WSS.  I have done some testing with this on a virtual environment by adding users to WSS, then taking them out of AD and creating them new usernames and upgrading the accounts and it had solved the issue a treat.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look on Google, the following answers popped up:

http://sharepointapplied.com/2009/02/04/move-sharepoint-to-a-new-domain/

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2007/09/moving-sharepoint-to-new-active.html. This looks HIGHLY UNSUPPORTED though!

Comment: Hi Colun,  You're right, the top option indicates (at the end) to use the STSADM migrateuser command (as djeeg mentions below) and the second one looks too risky, especially as it is unsupported.  Thanks for the feedback